# Minimum range required to visit N nodes in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

The problem statement is given at [problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CLZDOUGH/)

We are provided with an electric car and we need to visit N houses(Starting from any house) and each house has a charging station. There is at least one path of roads connecting each pair of houses. A trip from one house to any other must be completed using at most C recharging's. Car should always be recharged at the beginning of each trip(this counts as one of the C recharging's).Given the road network and C, **compute the minimum range** required of the electric car.

**Note:** With one recharging, the car can travel a distance equal to its range.

I tried to do this with Dijkstra , but couldn't define states properly.
I also tried with memoized recursion with states

```
dp[node][no of recharging done][Assumed range][range that still can be traveled without recharging]
```

but as distance between nodes can be in order of 10^9 so it is not possible to follow this approach as memory overflow would occur.
How can this be done?

Example : - let houses = 4 and recharges available =2 
Let a,b,c denote a bidirectional path from house a to b with distance c.

```
0 1 100
1 2 200
2 3 300
```

If we assume the range to be 300,we can go from 0 to 1(with recharging at 0 ,because we start from here) with 200 range left than from 1 to 2 with zero range left,recharge at 2 and get to 3 with 0 range left. hence our assumption is correct and there is no lesser range which can reach all houses with the same or lesser recharges i.e. 2.

similarly for 
houses =10 ,recharges =2
and paths as under:-

```
0 1 113
1 2 314
2 3 271
3 4 141
4 0 173
5 7 235
7 9 979
9 6 402
6 8 431
8 5 462
0 5 411
1 6 855
2 7 921
3 8 355
4 9 113
```

Ans should come out as 688.

Comment: Now if we consider C=1, you have to visit all N houses in one go. Sounds much like a TSP. So this problem will be NP hard I suppose.

Comment: @Sri.U I have updated the question with two examples .

Comment: @coderhacker Time limit for the task is 1 sec with  6 test cases and house, recharges (1 < house < 101, 0 < recharge < 101) and distance (1<distance <10^9 ) ,aren't these too high for a brute force tsp like solution?

Comment: @Sri.U I think as the judge expects the optimum answer,There is no other way than to use brute force?

Comment: @Sri.U btw why is it analogous to tsp as we don't need to visit houses exactly once but may do so multiple times until each house is visited?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104042/discussion-between-sam-and-sri-u).